# Tooltip p:outputLabel

Tags: primefaces, tooltip

I want to use tooltip in `<p: outputLabel>`. Right now I'm doing it this way but it does not work:

```
<p:outputLabel for="#{idInput}" value="#{etiqueta}" id="label-#{idInput}" title="#{etiqueta}">
</p:outputLabel>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does it not work? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: i want show the "tooltip" in the label.

Comment: Have you tried using a primefaces `tooltip` ?

Comment: Yes but it does not work. in other type components, yes it works

Comment: You should use `<p:tooltip>`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use `<p:tooltip>` which is available in primefaces.

Sample code:

```
  <p:outputLabel id="test" value="labelText" />

   <p:tooltip id="toolTipId" for="test" value="Sample tooltip"/>
```

if you want to use title attribute, below code will work. You should not use `id="label-#{idInput}"` "-" in id.
Sample code:

```
<p:outputLabel for="sam" value="hello"
            id="sam" title="test tooltip">
</p:outputLabel>
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me, I think the problem may come from the fact that the label is inside a custom component.

Comment: In your original question, you didn't mention the custom component.  You want to show tool tip with output label. Where exactly you are using the custom component?